# Existence of closed form solutions on a definite integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to find the value of the given expression in a closed form

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin x}{ x} dx$$

**My effort:**

I know that its a standard definite integral called $Si(x)$

$\sin x= x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}-\dfrac{x^7}{7!}+ \dots$

The integral of the expression becomes

$x-\dfrac{x^3}{3\cdot3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5\cdot5!}-\dfrac{x^7}{7\cdot7!}+ \dots$

Now I just need to put limits. The answer what *wolframalpha* says is $Si(\dfrac\pi 2)\approx 1.37076$

I just want to know whether there's a closed form or a pretty answer to this

$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}(x-\dfrac{x^3}{3\cdot3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5\cdot5!}-\dfrac{x^7}{7\cdot7!}+ \dots$) ? Something like $\dfrac{e}{2}$?

Comment: may be you can try wallis formula

Comment: Well, great hint. But I gotta find the limit of the *integral* and the Wallis product surely helps if it was just to find the $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} (\dfrac{\sin x}{x})$.

Comment: I would be *very* surprised if there were a closed form answer to this one.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I doubt whether there is any closed form solutions.

Comment: You can have a solution in terms of the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) $Si(\pi/2)$.